# how to configure multiple maven profiles and dynamic configuration with Maven

Tags: maven-3

I wish to define profiles for test, dev and prod in my pom.xml. However, I also want my application to be able to run under any of these environments at run time, using a system variable which is used by Spring too.

The question is where can I define my database properties in one place exclusively? Currently I have that in pom.xml in the profile definition, but I also have created db-test.properties, db-dev.properties and db-prod.properties in my application's resources/ folder. What is the best way to accomplish this? One thought was how can I turn the definitions in the pom.xml profiles into respective db-${env}.properties for all profiles using filtering?

Comment: Could you describe better your problem, also with some snippets of code?